May we find the digital text renderings of the Herculaneum scrolls?
I'm not sure, but this seems to be the closest to an "official website" for the Herculaneum scrolls:
https://scrollprize.org/data_scrolls
It recaps the technologies used and has explainers for file extensions involved in the scans.
What it seems to be lacking is a repository of the texts reconstructed so far (lacunic or otherwise) -- ideally with an English translation.
Seemingly, every few months there will be a headline in the news about progress with the Herculaneum scrolls and some highlights will be featured, but this can feel like a drip feed. And I can't imagine progress is that uneven, surely there would be more frequent uploads of the recovered text (in plain text) as they are processed.
Question
May we find a repository somewhere that contains all the reconstructed text so far?

There will always be a lag between what's online and new discoveries, but there are several places you access the papyri.
You can see the pictures of the papyri on Chartes, but the website is all in Italian. It bills itself as a complete and updated catalog of the papyri,

Il Catalogo dei Papiri Ercolanesi online è nato con il duplice intento di aggiornare il Catalogo cartaceo (con i due Supplementi) e di fornire un nuovo strumento di lavoro a quanti si occupano dei papiri di Ercolano.
Nella prima versione pubblicata online sono stati inclusi i dati aggiornati al 2005 (versione CD). Sono stati effettuati e sono previsti ulteriori aggiornamenti comprendenti i dati delle ricerche e le pubblicazioni più recenti.

For transcriptions, the Thesaurus Herculanensium Voluminum is online, hosted by the Würzburg Centre for Studies on Epicureanism, and this site notes an English translation here.
You can find more resources at The Herculaneum Society's website.

This is a crazy time to be alive. I really hope they find some Heraclitus or the other Prometheus plays by Aeschylus in the Herculaneum scrolls. You?
